# "Virtual" authentification with Auth0

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, auth0

I'm creating nodejs application, with graphql, mongodb.

Now I'm deciding which authentification system to use. 
My authentification flow is:

- user does some actions, all his actions are written to DB
- then, at the end of user's process, I show to user authentification form
- user can refuse or authenficate
- if user authenficates, I merge all actions made by this user with real user account.

I thought up the following solution:

When user enters to the site for the first time (he doesn't have accessToken), I create user with type "virtual" in DB, and send to front token of this "virtual" user.
Then, when user authenficates, I get his real ID, and update all DB documents: change virtual user ID to real user ID.

But then I thought about user's experience, about auth with social networks. Then I met a solution: Auth0. As authors say, this solution solves all the problems with authenfication and can give a good user and developer experience. But I found nothing about "virtual user" or something like it.

To sum up, **I have two questions**:

1. Is my authenfication flow a good practice? Or I can do it better?
2. Can I do it with Auth0? Can this solution help me to make good user
       experience?

Comment: Question regarding this flow: if the user refuses to create an account, and he closes the browser and comes back next time, all his information is gone and he has to start from scratch, is that correct? In such case: what are you doing with this kind of orphaned data in the DB that will never be used again?
Regarding whether it's possible with Auth0 - short answers: yes, definitely. (Disclaimer: I work as solutions engineer at Auth)

Comment: Auth0 comes into play when the user decides to authenticate/signup. How to create the reference between "anonymous" account and the "real" user account depends on the DB structure, but sounds like a valid approach. Do you then want to rely on social networks only, or also offer regular username/password option? (Disclaimer: I work at Auth0 as Solutions Engineer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If "anonymous" user closes browser, he won't lose all the information, because he won't lose access and refresh tokens and will continue to work as the same "anonymous" user. Regarding the kind data: in MVP I do nothing with the excessive data, but, if it affects performance a will remove this data by cron. In the third: of course I would like offer  regular username/password option and social networks.

Comment: How did he get this access and/or refresh token when he never authenticated before? Is that an access and refresh token in the sense as with OAuth2/OpenID Connect? You store this in a cookie?

Comment: When he visits site first time I create "virtual" user in DB and sentd to front access+ refresh tokens to this user. Front saves the tokens to localstorage and signs all requests with the access token. If the access token expire, front will update it with refresh token.  Token is just jwt token.

Comment: Ok, just note that localstorage isn't the safest place for it. https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#single-page-apps

Comment: The question is: can Auth0 helps me to realize this flow? I don't want to realize token update service, token provider on front. I know that this already realized in Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react#install-the-auth0-react-wrapper    

But how can I merge this with my "virtual" token flow? maybe You know a simple example, how to get Auth0 to generate "virtual" user without showing any authentication form?

Comment: Yes, you can choose the relevant Auth0 quickstart based on your technology stack and involve Auth0 when the user decides to authenticate and create the account. You receive back ID token (and access token). You can then link your local anonymous account with the one on Auth0 end (store user_id you receive from Auth0 on our end/DB as reference). Auth0 doesn't handle the anonymous user logic though beforehand, that's up to your app logic individually.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that can do what I want. May be I will come back with practical questions, not theoretical ones.